# split a word into letters in c++?

Tags: c++, string

how can to split a word in a string into the letters.
for example "hello" to "h", "l", "l", "o" and store them in an array.

Comment: Too much ambiguity here, what's a word, what's a letter etc. It's best to pose your question in terms of actual code, not descriptions of code, which are always easy to misinterpret.

Comment: @john "What's a word, what's a letter" Are you serious?

Comment: Yes, for instance the letters in the question have double quotes, so does the OP want strings of one letter? And what kind of string do they want, C or C++?

Comment: @john Yes? That's literally what the example says? Not sure of the purpose of your nitpicking but I am absolutely sure of its value

Comment: Maybe but I wouldn't answer this kind of question based on that assumption, and the C or C++ string issue isn't specified at all.

Comment: Just trying to get the OP to pose their question a bit better. Not that I think that's very likely.

Comment: It doesn't need to be. If you don't understand the question, @john, that's fine, you can just move on to another one. :)

Comment: `auto letters = std::vector<char>(s.begin(), s.end());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the string as if i would be a array. In a `c++`'s `std::string` if `example` equals `"Hello world!"` then `example[0]` equals `'H'`, `example[1]` equals `'e'` and so on.

If you really need to copy the string to an array of chars for some reason, you can use the `strcpy` function from the `string.h` library. Here an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string example = "Hello world!";
    char arr[example.length()];
    strcpy(arr,example.c_str());
    for(int i = 0; i < example.length(); i++)
        std::cout << arr[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable-length arrays are non-standard until C++17, and you don't need `arr` anyway since `std::string` overloads `operator[]`.

Comment: @StephenNewell what do you mean that VLA is non-standard until C++17?

Comment: Using VLA, which is not allowed in C++, `using namespace std` omg

Comment: Why do you need the array?  You can access `std::string` as if it was an array:  `std::cout << example[i] << "\n";`

Comment: @Slava - VLAs weren't part of standard C++ until C++17.

Comment: You want `#include <string>` and `using std::string;` not `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @StephenNewell which means that it is in C++17? Can you point where VLA is in C++17?

Answer (score 1):

It's already an array. :)

Strings are (or are exposed as) arrays of characters, even when hidden behind a controlling class like `std::string`.

So, if you need to use it with array subscript syntax (e.g. `myString[i]`), then simply do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s="Hello";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        printf("%c,",s[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post answers with `using namespace std;`.  You are not using the `#include<string.h>`.  However, you are using `#include <string>`.  I recommend you add "using std::string;`.